# Transfer object from one application to another

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is there a way to transfer object from one application to another? I mean something like that:

//FirstApp:

```
- (void)someFunction{
myClass *myObj = [[myClass alloc] init]

//do some work...

[self runSecondAppWithObj:myObj];
}
```

//SecondApp:

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        myClass *obj = //get obj from firstApp
        //do some another work...
    }
    return 0;
}
```

myClass not so simple, what is why I can't transfer all info with NSString -> char. Also I need exactly the first object in second app, and not its duplicate.

I imagine it like:
first app launches second app, after that first app talk to second: "Hey, #adr is the address to variable(pointer), go and take it". After, second app take variable(pointer) with it's address. But i don't know how to make it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options that immediately come to my mind for doing this (I would recommend implementing the first option):

1. **Make `myClass` serializable**: The basic idea here is that you implement the `NSCoding` protocol and then use `NSKeyedArchiver` for serializing it into an `NSDictionary`. The dictionary can then easily be converted to an interchangeable format, e.g. a plist (XML). You would then pass the XML text to your second application and deserialize it there using `NSDictionary` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`. You can find good guides and examples about [archiving and serialization in Cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i) in Apple's developer documentation.
2. **Pass the object using some inter process communication mechanism**: This is a bit more complex and I  would rather recommend it for apps that talk to each other continuously – not for just passing an object to another app on launch. One way to do this is using [distributed objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/DistrObjects.html). This enables you to share objects between processes or even between different physical machines as if they were local (with some limitations.) For example to share the object in your first app you might do:

   ```
   NSConnection *connection = [[NSConnection connectionWithReceivePort:[NSPort port]] sendPort:nil];
   [connection setRootObject:theObject];
   [connection registerName:@"com.example.whatever"];
   ```

   And in the second app you would then call:

   ```
   id theObject = (id)[NSConnection rootProxyForConnectionWithRegisteredName:@"com.example.whatever" host:nil];
   [theObject someMethod];
   ```